# what is the difference between the following two mail function?

Tags: php

I can't seem to work out why for the first code, I am getting a t_string error with my syntax because it looks the same as my second code:

```
 $htmlContent = "<h1>Congratulation Level 1 Promo Winner!</h1>
                                                                          <p>Dear $_SESSION['u_first'] $_SESSION['u_last'], <br /> Thank you for participating in our Level 1 Promo Competition recently. You have been selected as a winner in the following competition id: $row['entry_id']. You must activate your Level 1 Promo Code by clicking on the following link here <a href=https://www.pianocourse101.com/includes/activatelevel1promo.php?email=".htmlspecialchars($to)."&activatetoken=".htmlspecialchars($level1promocode).">Click here to activate your Level 1 Promo Code.</a>Alternatively, you can use the following token to manually activate your Level 1 Promo Code by clicking on the Activate Membership Section Token:.$level1promocode
                                                                      </p>";
```

and compared with this code:

```
 $htmlContent = "<h1>Activate your Primer Level Membership Plan!</h1>
                                                                          <p>Dear $first $last, <br />Thank you for registering your Primer Level Membership Plan with PianoCourse101! You are receiving this e-mail because you or someone else claiming to be you has selected a Primer Level Membership Plan \n\nIf you believe that this is a mistake, please send us a ticket with the subject \"How to cancel my Primer Level Membership Plan?\" and allow at least 48 hours before receiving a reply.\n\nHowever, if this is correct, then you must activate your Primer Level Membership Plan by clicking on the link below: \n\n <a href=https://www.pianocourse101.com/includes/activate.php?email=".htmlspecialchars($to)."&activatetoken=".htmlspecialchars($token4).">Click here to activate your Primer Level Membership Plan.</a>\n\nAlternatively, you can use the following token to manually activate your Level 3 Yearly Membership Plan by clicking on the 'Activate Membership\s Section:' \n\nToken:.$token4;
                                                                      </p>";
```

Comment: Please read about [How to create a *Minimal*, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Formatting would also help your question tremendously. It’s extremely difficult to read two super-long lines of code, much less debug them.

Comment: I know what is wrong... It was a syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on your first code. which is using $_SESSION[], that is a array. if you want to concatenate string with array value then you need to place proper Quotation marks (").

on your second code you are using variable. in that you can concatenate string with variable value normally as you are doing

you can check your first code from here. i have made update some " marks.

```
   $htmlContent = "<h1>Congratulation Level 1 Promo Winner!</h1><p>Dear ".$_SESSION['u_first'].$_SESSION['u_last'].", <br /> Thank you for participating in our Level 1 Promo Competition recently. You have been selected as a winner in the following competition id:". $row['entry_id']." You must activate your Level 1 Promo Code by clicking on the following link here <a href=https://www.pianocourse101.com/includes/activatelevel1promo.php?email=".htmlspecialchars($to)."&activatetoken=".htmlspecialchars($level1promocode).">Click here to activate your Level 1 Promo Code.</a>Alternatively, you can use the following token to manually activate your Level 1 Promo Code by clicking on the Activate Membership Section Token:$level1promocode</p>";
```

Comment: Thanks... I have figured that out but now I am getting this error but my url is correct

Answer (score 0):

First Code :

here session is creating for specific user by below code:

```
$_SESSION['u_first'] $_SESSION['u_last']
```

Second code:
Here we already created session and assigned for variables so that is used to display user information